# Ill formed code snippets

Tags: c++

can somebody please tell me the difference between the following two code snippets:

```
//Code snippet A: Compiles fine
int main()
{
    if(int i = 2)
    {
        i = 2 + 3;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}

//Code Snippet B: Doesn't compile :(
int main()
{
    if((int i = 2))
    {
        i = 2 + 3;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

If you notice the diff is just an extra parenthesis at if statement. I am using g++ compiler.Error is "expected primary-expression before âintâ"

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Neither code makes much sense.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516919/declaring-and-initializing-a-variable-in-a-conditional-or-control-statement-in-c

Comment: just trying to understand c++ Graham.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Section 6.4 of the C++ standard (draft n2914 of c++0x) has this to say about the format of `if` statements:

> Selection statements choose one of several flows of control.
>      `selection-statement:`
>         `if ( condition ) statement`
>         `if ( condition ) statement else statement`
>         `switch ( condition ) statement`
>      `condition:`
>         `expression`
>         `type-specifier-seq attribute-specifieropt declarator = initializer-clause`
>         `type-specifier-seq attribute-specifieropt declarator braced-init-list`

That bit at the end means a condition can be either an expression *or* a decalarator-type construct.

And the minute the parser hits that second parenthesis, it becomes an expression, so no declarations allowed, I'm afraid.

The snippet:

```
if (int i = 2) { ... } else { ... }
```

is perfectly valid C++ in which the if section defines an integer `i` for the duration of the `if/else` and sets it to 2. It then uses that 2 as the input to the `if` (2 is always true, being non-zero).

The snippet `if((int i = 2))` is no different syntactically to `int x = (int i = 2;); if (x)` which is *not* valid C++.

Answer (score 10):

Snippet A is fine - the `if` condition delares and initialises a variable that can be interpreted as a boolean. The variable is defined within the `if` and any `else` blocks.

Snippet B is wrong, because you can't put parentheses around a declaration - you can only put them round expressions. The following is also wrong for the same reason:

```
int main()
{
    int i;       // OK
    (i = 2);     // OK

    (int x = 2); // compile error
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! simple and the best answer :) ..wish i could vote..not registered yet.

Comment: Well, register so you can. Although I can't agree it's the *best* answer, it's certainly a good succinct one, especially for those here not willing to sit through my usual essays to find a gem of good information:-) I've already upvoted it.

Comment: upvoting is to encourage..right? ..and am philanthropist anyways :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is another variant of second snippet error:

```
int main()
{
    int i = (int j = 0);
    return 0;
}
```

You can't declare variables inside ANY expression.
Second () inside for is the same case - you can declare variable i inside for() but not inside nested expression placed into ().

Hope I explained it in proper words, maybe more correct explanation exists. Actually both code fragments are odd.

Answer (score 1):

Both look wrong.

Just because code compiles it doesn't mean it's valid.  I'm surprised that the first case is compiling, since it seems like `i` isn't defined in the else case.

edit: I'm wrong here, definitions in the `if` condition are valid for that whole `if` / `else` statement.

Comment: The scope of the int declarator is to the end of the *entire* if statement.

Comment: Not only that, but the expression inside the if is performing an assignment not a comparison, and as such the else case will never be reached.

Comment: The first case is perfectly valid C++. It doesn't have to be useful. 'if (0)' is also perfectly valid C++ despite it's uselessnes.

Comment: yeah..compilation and coding these is not an issue ..I was just trying to understand "the ill formed cpp statements".

Comment: ..I mean, the snippets are useless and we will never write such codes..but there are few not so known things about c++.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't realise that `if (int i = 0) {} else { i = 1; } ` was valid code.

Comment: else is not that useful with literals, but you'd generally :) see things like `if (X* p = foo())`

Comment: Makes sense, maybe I knew it, I'd just never thought that through. :)