# How does one declare a variable inside an if () statement?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Declaring and initializing a variable in a Conditional or Control statement in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516919/declaring-and-initializing-a-variable-in-a-conditional-or-control-statement-in-c)

Instead of this...

```
int value = get_value();
if ( value > 100 )
{
    // Do something with value.
}
```

... is it possible to reduce the scope of *value* to only where it is needed:

```
if ( int value = get_value() > 100 )
{
    // Obviously this doesn't work. get_value() > 100 returns true,
    // which is implicitly converted to 1 and assigned to value.
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do `if(get_value() > 100)` ?

Comment: @noko: Not if you want to do something with the value.

Comment: Can you explain this a little bit more? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Do you actually need `value` for anything else?

Comment: i think that is the reason why they introduced for loops

Comment: @MayankSharma: I think not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i am just saying that there are ways of doing it using different constructs..

Comment: @MayankSharma: Actually, that's _not_ what you said!

Comment: if ( (int value = get_value()) > 100 )
{

}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want specific scope for value, you can introduce a scope block.

```
#include <iostream>

int get_value() {
    return 101;
}

int main() {
    {
        int value = get_value();
        if(value > 100)
            std::cout << "Hey!";
    } //value out of scope
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Can you declare a variable and compare it within the `if()` statement? No.
Can you declare a variable and compare it in such a way that the scope is tightly-bound to the `if()` block? **Yes!**

---

You can *either* declare a variable:

```
if (int x = 5) {
   // lol!
}
```

**or** you can *do things* with one:

```
int x = foo();
if (x == 5) {
   // wahey!
}
```

You can't do both!

---

You *can* cheat a little where the only thing you need to do is compare with `true`, because the declaration itself evaluates to the value of the new object.

So, if you have:

```
int foo()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Then this:

```
if (int x = foo()) {
    // never reached
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
{
   int x = foo();
   if (x) {
       // never reached
   }
}
```

---

This final syntax, using a standalone scope block, is also your golden bullet for more complex expressions:

```
{
   int x = foo();
   if (x > bar()) {
       // wahooza!
   }
}
```

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Did you post your comment on the wrong answer? It appears to have nothing to do with what I said. There is nothing "brittle" about basic `if` syntax, which will always "work".

Answer (score 6):

Put it in a function:

```
void goodName(int value) {
    if(value > 100) {
        // Do something with value.
    }
}

//...
    goodName(get_value());
```

Answer (score 5):

How about using `for` instead?

```
for (int value = get_value(); value > 100; value = 0) {
    //...
}
```

If you want to go C++11 on it, you can use a lambda:

```
[](int value = get_value()) {
    if (value > 100) {
        //...
        std::cout << "value:" << value;
    }
}();
```

Comment: Write-only code.

Comment: Because this is not error-prone or inexpressive at all.

Comment: I think *for (int value = get_value(); value > 100; **value = 0**)* would be a bit better. No need to use `break`.

Comment: Using a C++ lambda for this is using a hammer where a stapler is needed. Overdoing, I say.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just add an extra set of braces for a nested scope, although it's not exactly pretty:

```
{
    int value = get_value();
    if ( value > 100 )
    {
        // Do something with value.
    }   
}
//now value is out of scope
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small function which can do the comparison for you and return the value the if comparison returns true, else return `0` to avoid executing the `if` block:

```
int greater_than(int right, int left)
{
   return left > right ? left : 0;
}
```

Then use it as:

```
if ( int value = greater_than(100, get_value()))
{
      //wow!
}
```

Or you can use `for` as other answer said. Or manually put braces to reduce the scope of the variable.

At any rate, I would **not**  write such code in production code.

Don't write code for machines. Write code for humans. Machines will understand anything as long as you follow their grammar; humans understand what is readable to them. So readability should be your priority over *unnecessary* scoping.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you can bodge it:

```
if (int value = (get_value() > 100 ? get_value() : 0)) {
    ...
}
```

I don't really recommend it, though. It doesn't work for all possible tests that you might want to perform, and it calls `get_value()` twice.

Comment: Why not `if(get_value() > 100) { int value = get_value(); ....}`

Comment: @Nawaz: because the questioner posed a contrived restriction (i.e. no good reason -- I wouldn't write this in real code and your suggestion is better). In fact, if the number of calls to `get_value()` doesn't matter then I probably wouldn't assign it to a variable at all, just type `get_value()` in the body of the loop however many times it's needed :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: No good reason? Restricting the scope of variables isn't "no good reason" :)

Comment: @DrTwox: sure, but adding the extra block is the "real" answer I'd have given if it wasn't already mentioned, or if calling `get_value()` twice is OK then what Nawaz says in the comment above beats this when there is no `else` clause. Actually Nawaz's answer is a potential improvement on this anyway. I'd tinker a bit with it, I don't *love* the idea of a function whose first param is called `right` and the second `left`!