# How to declare a variable in the brackets of if statement?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to declare a local variable in the brackets of an if statement.
For example.

```
if((char c = getc(stdin)) == 0x01)//This is not OK with g++.
{
    ungetc(c, stdin);
}
```

What I want is, to see if the character is the one I want.
To say it commonly, I want to use the variable(char c) both in the line of *if* and the body of *if*, but not outside the *if*.

But g++(GCC 4.8.1) says *expected primary-expression before 'char'*.
I wonder if there's a way to do that, because I don't want something like

```
char c = getc(stdin);
if(c == 0x01)
{
    bla...
}
```

Comment: You could abuse the `for` loop.

Comment: If it's about pollution, you can always use a new scope, or the for loop.

Comment: The most succinct (stupid) solution is probably `if ( int c = getc( stdin ) - 1 ) ; else ungetc( c + 1 );`.

Comment: Why this limitation of not lifting the variable definition and initialization out of the condition?

Comment: @GManNickG Fung shui?

Comment: @SLaks: That must be the biggest abuse I've heard of in a while, which is nevertheless such a cool idea that I'm almost tempted to _find a place_ to use it. `for(char c = getc(stdin); c == 0x01; ) {...}` -- not precisely principle-of-least-confusion, but awesome :-)    Except... how does it exit, ever?

Comment: @Damon Fill in the last part: `for(char c = getc(stdin); c == 0x01; c = 42)`

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Ah right, of course :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one declare a variable inside an if () statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620898/how-does-one-declare-a-variable-inside-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it's the namespace pollution you are worrying about you can always define the `if` statement within a block:

```
{
    char c = getc(stdin);
    if(c == 0x01)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So that `c` will only last until the end of the block is reached.

Comment: Though didn't answer the question, this way of writting code is simple, clear and effective. Thank you.

Comment: @qlb1234 Sometimes a question, as in your case, is effectively asking  "how do I best write bad code". These questions aren't supposed to be answered with "this is how you write bad code", but with "don't write bad code, do this instead." :-)

Comment: @NikosC.: The appeal of this answer is its simplicity, but I rarely find such constructs acceptable in a code review. When I see a standalone statement block like this, I always think the code should be in a separate function.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't know how to create a variable and test its value with an `if` until after seeing some of the posted solutions. However, you could use `switch`. This would allow you to react to additional values (perhaps `EOF`):

```
switch (int c = getc(stdin)) {
case 0x01: ungetc(c, stdin); break;
case EOF:  // ...handle EOF
default:   break;
}
```

You could always place the `if` statement in an inlined function instead, and the code will look a little cleaner. If you really want the source code right at that location, but without creating a new scope around an `if` with a new variable, then perhaps a lambda would be acceptable to you.

```
[](int c){ if (c == 0x01) ungetc(c, stdin); }(getc(stdin));
```

Since you are only comparing against one valuem your particular problem does not require a variable at all, so you can simply do:

```
if (getc(stdin) == 0x01) {
    char c = 0x01;
    ungetc(c, stdin); //or bla...
}
```

If you are wanting to compare against a set of values, then the `switch` suggestion is the better option.

Jerry Coffin's solution looks appealing, but it really boils down to:

```
if (int c = (getc(stdin) == 0x01)) //...
```

This is probably not what you really wanted, as it does not generalize well if you want to compare to a value different from `0x01`.

Potatoswatter's solution seems closer to what you want, but perhaps it would be nicer to pull the type out into a standalone class:

```
template <typename T>
class SetAndTest {
    const T test_;
    T set_;
public:
    SetAndTest (T s = T(), T t = T()) : set_(s), test_(t) {}
    operator bool () { return set_ == test_; }
    operator bool () const { return set_ == test_; }
    operator T & () { return set_; }
    operator T () const { return set_; }
};

//...
if (auto c = SetAndTest<int>(getc(stdin), 0x01)) {
    ungetc(c, stdin); //or bla...
}
```

Comment: Wow, never thought of that.

Comment: why are you repeating operator overload?

Answer (score 8):

You *can* define the variable inside the `if` statement just fine. For example, this should compile:

```
if (int ch = getchar())
    ;
```

The problem is that the type (e.g., `int`) must follow *immediately* after the opening parenthesis. The extra parenthesis you have is what's causing compilation to fail. So, if you really want to do this, you'll need to get a little clever and use something like this:

```
if (char ch = 0 || ((ch = getchar()) == 0x1))
```

This lets you get the creation and initialization of `ch` done, *then* after that part of the expression is complete, put in the parentheses around the `ch=getchar()` to override the precedence of assignment vs. comparison.

Note that `&&` and `||` do short-circuit evaluation, so you need to be careful with your initialization. You can use either:

```
if (char ch = 0 || ...
```

...or:

```
if (char ch = 1 && ...
```

...but if you try to use `if (ch = 1 || ...` or `if (ch = 0 && ...`, the short-circuit evaluation will keep the right operand (the part you really care about) from being evaluated at all.

Now the caveat: while I'm reasonably certain this code fits the standard's requirements, and most (all?) current compilers will accept it, it's likely to cause most programmers reading the code some serious head-scratching figuring out what you've done, and why. I'd be extremely hesitant (at best) about using this "technique" in real code.

Edit: It's been pointed out that the result from this may be even more misleading than some initially expect, so I'll try to clarify the situation. What happens is that a value is read from input. That value is assigned to `ch` and compared to `0x1`. So far so good. After that, the result of the comparison (converted to an integer, so either `0` or `1`) will be assigned to `ch`. I believe it has sufficient sequence points that the result is defined behavior. But it's probably not what you, or anybody, want -- thus the advice that you probably don't want to use this, and the mention that it would probably leave most programmers scratching their heads, wondering what you were trying to do. In the very specific case of comparing to 0x1, the value of `ch` inside the `if` statement will be `1`, but it's more or less a coincidence. If you were comparing to 0x2, the value of `ch` inside the `if` would still be `1`, not `2`.

Comment: Couldn't you also use a comma?

Comment: @sje397: Oddly enough, no -- not allowed in this case.

Comment: What does the `0 ||` part do? It looks like `ch = true` will inevitably happen after `ch = getchar()`.

Comment: Wikipedia notes this as a use case for the comma operator in examples/condition here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator. But they did once say the Great Wall was made of Star Wars action figures...

Comment: @sje397: Every compiler I have rejects the code if you try to use a comma (and I believe the standard requires them to do so).

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Oops -- need yet another set of parens to the right. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @JerryCoffin **-1**, no matter how many parens you put in there a boolean will always end up in `ch`. ie. `char ch = 0 || ((ch = getchar()) == 42)` will never have `ch == 42` inside the body of the *if-statement*.

Comment: @refp: When all is said and done, yes -- but that's not what he asked about, is it? When the value is tested, it has the value that came from `getchar()`, which is what he seems to care about.

Comment: @JerryCoffin and you think that makes sense? he wants to use `ch` (ie. the value of `getchar ()`) inside the *if-statement*, if he just wanted to test the value of `getchar ()` `getchar () == ...` would be sufficient. your answer implies that the value of `getchar ()` will be stored in `ch` and remain there inside the *if-statement*; something which isn't true. **quote from op**: *"To say it commonly, I want to use the variable(char c) both in the line of if and the body of if, but not outside the if."*

Comment: @refp: I think you're inferring something that's not really implied anywhere. It doesn't seem to me to make much sense anyway -- he's specifically testing for equality to 1, so the only value it can have inside the `if` statement is one anyway (otherwise, nothing inside the `if` statement can execute).

Comment: @JerryCoffin sure, but then you should also mention that what you are doing is equivalent to `if (getchar () == 0x1) { /* just use 'true' instead of ch in here */ }`

Comment: @refp Yeah, that's true. The level of logical OR(`||`) is higher than the one of assignment(`=`). If written as above mentioned, `ch` will never equals to `getchar()`, and the body of `if` will never know the value of `getchar()`. If so, why would this question exsit? I've almost accept this answer for a mistake, but what he thinks is still clever.

Comment: "This lets you get the creation and initialization of ch done, then [...]" actually the right hand side of the `||` is still part of the initialization expression. The syntax of the `if` condition is either an expression or a single declaration; there is no 'declaration followed by expression' and so your code is structured such that the expression is hidden inside a declaration's initializer.

Comment: Additionally your code does not do the intended thing, as you say `ch` gets reassigned to 1 or 0, and does not keep the desired value that resulted from `getchar()`.

Comment: N.B. this code is only well-defined because `char` does not have a non-trivial constructor, if you tried `if (NonTrivialInit p = 0 || ((p = something()) == x))` it would be undefined because `p` is assigned to before it has been initialized. Bad Things will happen.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm not sure I see the reason for the double assignment in `if(char ch = 0 || ((ch = getchar()) == 0x1))`. Wouldn't `if(char ch = 0 || (getchar() == 0x1))` be equivalent? And while we're at it ... `if(char ch = (getchar() == 0x1))` is still the same logic, only more readable [;-)](http://goo.gl/gOGev)