# why I cannot do such a variable definition in if condition

Tags: c++, if-statement, dynamic-cast

The following statement gives me compiler error as a surprise to me:

```
BaseClass& base;

if (((const AClass*) ptr = dynamic_cast<const AClass*> (&base)) != NULL)
{
  ...
}
```

GCC 4.1.2 says ptr isn't defined as an error. However an ordinary defintion and assignment would work. Such as

```
if (const int* ptr = f())
```

So what makes it not working for the above code segment?

No this isn't a duplication of the other thread as I have pointed out the simple case works but not such a case. If you think it's a duplication can you at least point out why the above one doesn't work then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring and initializing a variable in a Conditional or Control statement in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516919/declaring-and-initializing-a-variable-in-a-conditional-or-control-statement-in-c)

Comment: Maybe you meant `if ( const AClass *ptr = dynamic_cast<const AClass *>(&base) )`

Comment: @M.M Tried all such variants but still same error.

Comment: @AlexSuo try exactly what I wrote, not some variants. [See it working](http://goo.gl/WNYxeT)

Comment: Alright I got a simple mistake then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
(const AClass*) ptr
```

is a cast of `ptr` to type `const AClass*`, not a declaration. If you haven't declared `ptr` already then you'll get the error you mentioned.

Comment: If you had declared `ptr` already it's still an error because the result of the cast is an rvalue, which cannot be assigned to.